# startProcess: posix_spawnp: does not exist (No such file or directory)

Tags: bash, systemd, posix

I have an interesting case where I'm getting the below error when running a bash program but only when it's run via a systemd unit (running within Nixos).

`telegram: startProcess: posix_spawnp: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

If I run this program from the command line locally it works with no issue... What might be the cause of this error? It seems like posix_spawnp is actually a syscall which confuses me (why does the error seem to indicate it's an executable?)

The actual script is located here: https://github.com/fabianonline/telegram.sh/blob/master/telegram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue was just that the `telegram` executable being called was not in the $PATH. My interpretation of the error (that it was actually looking for an executable named `posix_spawnp`) seems to be incorrect.